# How to select records if all of the conditions satisfies in sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables stage and hier table
stage table:

```
POL_NO  AGENT   COMPANY_CODE
100      001        01
101      002        01
102      003        01
103      004        01
```

hier table:

```
PAY_REASON  PAY_CODE    AGENCY_CODE FINANCIAL_AGENT COMPANY_CODE    AGENT
S               BO           -             -            01           001
P               -            H                          01           001
-               -            B             -            01           001
S               BO           B            420           01           002
S               BO           -             -            01           002
S               BO           -             -            01           003
P               DD           U             -            01           003
-               -            B             -            01           003
-               -            B             -            01           004
-               -            B             -            01           004
-               -            -            420           01           004
```

the stage table will compare with the hier table based on (company_code and agent) to look if the below criteria is met in the hier table:

```
1.(pay_reason='S'and pay_code='BO') or agency_code in ('B','H','U')
2.Financial agent!=420
```

If any of the records in hier table does not match the criteria,then the company_code and agent won't show up in the expected result

expected result:

```
POL_NO  AGENT   COMPANY_CODE
100      001        01
102      003        01
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you set up a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
Select *
From stage s
where not exists (
select *
from hier h
where s.AGENT = h.AGENT
And s.COMPANY_CODE = h.COMPANY_CODE
and not(((pay_reason='S'and pay_code='BO') or agency_code in ('B','H','U'))
and Financial_agent!=420))
```

Comment: @TirthaRoyChowdhury - I've updated my answer to return unique rows and explained why I think your expected outcome is wrong unless I'm misunderstanding the question

Comment: if any of the records does not match the criteria in hier table  ,then company_code+agent won't be considered

Comment: @TirthaRoyChowdhury - Okie dokie, edited above to reflect that, you might want to update the question to clarify this

Comment: @TirthaRoyChowdhury - If the answer above helped please can you mark it as the accepted answer, if not please could you tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190144/discussion-between-tirtha-roy-chowdhury-and-ryan-sparks).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the conditions correctly, you seem to want:

```
select *
from stage s
where not exists (select 1
                  from hier h
                  where s.agent = h.agent and
                        s.company_code = h.company_code and
                        h.Financial_agent = 420 and
                        not ( (h.pay_reason = 'S' and pay_code = 'BO') or
                               h.agency_code in ('B', 'H', 'U')                    
                            )
                 );
```